# System.Windows.Forms.TextBox not displaying output

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, textbox

I am trying to create a GUI for my script that will go and delete certain files that match a certain name that is older than a set time period in a directory and show a what if before deleting. Everything was going well until I tried to put the output into a Textbox. The output displays in the console fine but won't display in the textbox. I have narrowed it down to the command I am running, as if I simply remove it and run 'ping google.com' it outputs fine. Please find my code below:

```
$scanbutton.Location = '380,84'
$scanbutton.text = 'Scan Directory'
$scanbutton.height = 25
$scanbutton.Width = 100
$scanbutton.Add_Click({
    $result.Text = get-childitem $folderBrowser.SelectedPath -include "cat*.png" -force -recurse | where-object { (-not $_.PSIsContainer) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-0)) } | remove-item -whatif
    #$result.Text = ping google.com
    $Form.Controls.Add($result)
})
```

Anyone have any ideas why this is? I am still very new to all this so please be nice. Also how can I get the output to follow new lines like in the console? At the moment it just has it as one long string (when I do ping). Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Thank you in advance.
IC

Comment: `Remove-Item` does not [output anything](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.1#outputs) and why `(get-date).AddDays(-0))`? That means only files modified in **the future** will be filtered out... Also, read about the `MultiLine` property of a TextBox

Comment: Hey @Theo,
Thanks for looking at this. I don't really know what you mean by Remove-Item does not output anything. Having the -whatif at the end seems to output something in the console, which is what I want to display.
The (get-date).AddDays(-0)) was only set to 0 for testing. Eventually this will be set to -60 for example. 
The code alone works fine, and does what I need it to, just getting output in the TextBox is the issue. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: `-WhatIf` and `Write-Host` do is not **return** anything AFAIK, but instead directly write to the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, the `Remove-Item` cmdlet does not return anything you can capture as text in a textbox. Neither does the `-WhatIf` switch, which like `Write-Host` is designed to not **return** anything, but write directly onto the console.

In your case, you can create and write your own info in the TextBox. Something like:

```
$resultBox = [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]::new()
# do the Location, Size and whatever it takes here

# make the textbox accept multiple lines of text
$resultBox.Multiline = $true

# add the control to the form after you have created it
# NOT inside the $scanbutton.Add_Click() event handler
$Form.Controls.Add($resultBox)

$scanbutton.Add_Click({
    # get a list of files to remove (just the FullNames)
    $filesToRemove = Get-ChildItem $folderBrowser.SelectedPath -Filter "cat*.png" -File -Force -Recurse | 
                     Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60).Date) } | 
                     Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
                    
    # write the file FullNames in the textbox   
    $resultBox.Text = "Removing files:`r`n{0}" -f ($filesToRemove -join [environment]::NewLine)
    $filesToRemove | Remove-Item -WhatIf
})
```

Comment: Hey @Theo,
Thank you for being patient and explaining what the difference is between return and write. I really do appreciate it. I am new to this language and programming in general so it means a lot. Thanks again this works perfectly. Have a great day :)